# Load table from a database at the first reference in context

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4.0. I do a lot of read operations on the database (data analysis). No data will be saved. Currently, despite the Lazy Loading, number of I / O operations to the database server slows down considerably the application. I decided most of the small tables loaded into memory (`.ToList()`) and then generate the calculation. Is there a way to automatically read the context of the data in the table are only the first references to it and have not been updated by the life context?. The idea is that with further references to this table was not queried database, only the memory of the application.

Now, I use this code:

```
public class cDBReader
{
        private List<RISK_T_MEMBERS> fMembers;

        public List<RISK_T_MEMBERS> Members
        {
            get
            {
                if (fMembers == null)
                    using (RiskEntities context = new RiskEntities(TConfiguration.connectionString))
                    {
                        context.RISK_T_MEMBERS.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
                        fMembers = context.RISK_T_MEMBERS.ToList();
                    }

                return fMembers;
            }
            set { fMembers = value; }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add some more information? What is wrong with the current implementation?

It seems like what you need is some kind of caching. Here is an example implementation on [caching](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx).

An even simple ( less overkill in my opinion ) way to implement caching would be [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/04/22/tip-14-caching-entity-framework-reference-data.aspx).

Last but not least is any implementation of yours ( like the one you already made ). Maybe the singleton pattern could help you here? That is a singleton object that saves all those data you need globally and implements **gets** to your data by providing the context currently active, and in case the data is null, the application uses the active context to get them. Dropping and creating the context could also speed up the application after a while ( and that's the reason why I think you should provide the active context to the getData functions ).

Answer (score 0):

You could try Eager Loading instead of Lazy Loading first to get full control on what EF loads and just manually preload what you need once. Loaded data will stay alive within one context lifetime bounds, if you will need more and are sure that database is read only, you could just store somewhere and then attach preloaded data when new context is created